# Mouse issues: Unable to grab cursor

Tags: mouse

I've recently started loosing control of my mouse left-click.
Symptoms:

1. Unable to left click anywhere
2. Mouse cursor usually gets stuck on the insert cursor shape
3. running `xkill` will error with "unable to grab mouse cursor`

Suspected cause:
This usually starts when I've been alt-tabbing to swap windows too... aggressively. Maybe I'm mistyping a hotkey?

Debug info:
I have found that I can temporarily fix the issue by right-clicking the application icon in the launcher. I will then have my mouse back until I swap windows again (whether with the mouse or alt-tabbing)

Environment: 16.04LTS

How can I fix? Thanks.

Comment: I can not say this will fix your issue for sure but since 16.04 is EOL in April and will no longer have support this would be a good time to upgrade.